# Method not receiving attributes from shortcode call, general OOP problems

Tags: oop, wordpress

The method `OpenMods` that you see below, is supposed to take an array generated by an `fgetcsv` function, and put it into an HTML table. `__construct` is supposed to, as is typically the case, define the attributes for the class, and `shortcode` is supposed to take two attributes from the shortcode, and if mods comes back, it is supposed to call another function in the class.

`OpenMods` did function when it was outside of a class, without the class attribute calls, so I'm fairly certain that isn't the source of my problem. My problem most likely lies within `__construct` and `shortcode`; However please don't overlook OpenMods as it may contain errors that are contributing to the problem, I'm just giving my estimation which isn't worth much since I'm having to ask to for help.

This is an example of the shortcode I'm trying to make work:

```
[priceguide file=’test.csv’ type=’mods’]
```

---

```
class CsvImporter
{   
    private $parse_header;
    private $header;
    private $delimiter;
    private $length;
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
function __construct($parse_header=false, $delimiter="\t", $length=8000)
 {
    add_shortcode( 'priceguide', array( $this, 'shortcode' ) );
    $this->parse_header = $parse_header;
    $this->delimiter = $delimiter;
    $this->length = $length;
}
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
public function shortcode($atts) {
    $attributes = extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'file' => '',
        'type' => '',
    ), $atts ));
    if ($attributes['mods'])
    {
        $this->OpenMods($attributes['file']);
    }
}
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    function OpenMods($file) {
    ob_start();
     $fp = fopen(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )  . $file , "r" );
    if ($this->parse_header)
    {
       $header = fgetcsv($fp, $this->length, $this->delimiter); 
    }
    // table header and search html
    echo('<input type="text" class="search" id="search" placeholder="Search">');
    echo('<br>');
    echo('<table id="table">    <tr class="hidden">
        <th><b>
            Name</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>
            Cheese</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>
            Price</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>Vote</b>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>');
    // integer for drop down/price submit
    $a = 1;
    // set values for table data
    while ($header !== FALSE) {
        $name = $header[0];
        $quanid = $header[2];
        $table = $header[3];
        unset($header[2]);
        unset($header[3]);
        $cssId = 'row-'.$a;
        $a++;
        //generate HTML
        echo('<tr>');
        foreach ($header as $index=>$val) {
            echo('<td>');
            echo htmlentities($val, ENT_QUOTES);
            echo('</td>');  
        }
        // query to get item prices
        $sql = "SELECT ItemID, Price 
        FROM {$table}
        WHERE ItemID = %d
        GROUP BY Price
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1";
        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $quanid));
        // put the results in the table
        echo('<td>');
        print_r($results);
        echo('</td>');
        // HTML for hidden row/price submission
        echo('<td>
            <button class="toggler" data-prod-cat="' . $cssId . '">Vote</button>
        </td>');
        echo('</tr>');
        echo('<tr class="cat' . $cssId . ' hidden" style="display:none">');
        echo('<td colspan="4" style="white-space: nowrap">Enter ' . $name . ' Price:
        <form action="" name="form' . $quanid . '" method="post"><input type="text" id="' . $quanid . '" maxlength="4" name="' . $quanid . '" value="price_input" class="input" />
        <button id="submit" name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button></form>
        <?php
  ?>
        </td>
        </tr>');
        wp_nonce_field('price_input');
    }
    echo("</table>");
    fclose($fp);
    return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no key in your `$attributes` array, like `mods`. There are `type` key. I think, you want `$attributes['type'] == 'mods'`

Comment: and, do you create an instance of the object from this class, before you call the shortcode?

Comment: Hello, thanks much for the reply, I am not creating an instance of the object before calling the shortcode, could you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on OP comment, the problem is, the object can not created and in this case, `__constructor()` will not run, and `add_shortcode( 'priceguide', array( $this, 'shortcode' ) );` will never triggered.

There are two solutions. One, if you are make the `shortcode` method to static, and add this in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_shortcode( 'priceguide', 'CsvImporter::shortcode' ) );
```

The second option, if you do not want to make it static if you instantiate an object from your class, before anythings happens. In your `functions.php`

```
add_action('init', 'my_init');
global $CsvImporter;

function my_init() {
    global $CsvImporter;
    $CsvImporter = new CsvImporter();
}
```

In this case, when no output send to the buffer, you create a new `CsvImporter` object, so the `__construct()` will run, so `shortcode` will registered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I went with the second option, the shortcode now disappears when the plugin is activated, but there is no content on the page, it's blank.

Comment: Not sure, but as I know, in your shortcode function you need to `return`, not `echo`. But first, try to `return 'abc';` immediatly at the top of your `shortcode` method to check, is this method fired. Now I need to go, good luck.